# "Embedding/inheriting" one `data` constructor in another?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following fragment:

```
data File
    = NoFile
    | FileInfo {
        path :: FilePath,
        modTime :: Data.Time.Clock.UTCTime
    }
    | FileFull {
        path :: FilePath,
        modTime :: Data.Time.Clock.UTCTime,
        content :: String
    }
    deriving Eq
```

That duplication is a bit of a "wart", though in this one-off instance not particularly painful. In order to further improve my understanding of Haskell's rich type system, what might be preferred "clean"/"idiomatic" approaches for refactoring **other** than *either* simply creating a separate `data` record type for the 2 duplicate fields (then replacing them with single fields of that new `data` type) *or* replacing the `FileFull` record notation with something like `| FileFull File String`, which wouldn't be quite clean either (as here one would only want `FileInfo` in there for example, not `NoFile`)?

(Both these "naive" approaches would be somewhat intrusive/annoying with respect to having to then fix up many modules manually throughout the rest of the code-base here.)

One thing I considered would be parameterizing like so:

```
data File a
    = NoFile
    | FileMaybeWithContent {
        path :: FilePath,
        modTime :: Data.Time.Clock.UTCTime
        content :: a
    }
    deriving Eq
```

Then for those "just info, not loaded" contexts `a` would be `()`, otherwise `String`. Seems too general anyway, we want either `String` or nothing, leading us to `Maybe`, doing once again away with the `a` parameter.

Of course we've been there before: `content` could just be done with `Maybe String` of course, then "refactor any compile errors away" and "done". That'll probably be the order of the day, but knowing Haskell and the many funky GHC extensions.. *who knows* just *what* exotic theoretic trick/axiom/law I've been missing, right?! See, the differently-named "semantic insta-differentiator" between a "just meta-data info" value and a "file content with meta info" value does work well throughout the rest of the code-base as far as eased comprehension.

(And yes, I perhaps should have removed `NoFile` and used `Maybe File`s throughout, but then... not sure whether there's really a *solid* reason to do so and a different question altogether anyway..)

Comment: The original looks pretty good to me. Simple and clear.

Comment: I would remove the `NoFile` constructor, and instead use `Maybe File` in the right places. `NoFile` is a very strange kind of `File`. Haskell isn't Java!

Comment: Why do you need NoFile over Maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, the `NoFile` constructor is probably not necessary, but you can keep it if you want. If you feel your code is more readable and/or better understood with it, then I say keep it.

Now the trick with combining the other two constructors is by hiding the `content` field. You were on the right track by parameterizing `File`, but that alone isn't enough since then we can have `File Foo`, `File Bar`, etc. Fortunately, GHC has some nifty ways to help us.

I'll write out the code here and then explain how it works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.Void

data Desc = Info | Full

type family Content (a :: Desc) where
  Content Full = String
  Content    _ = Void

data File a = File
  { path :: FilePath
  , modTime :: UTCTime
  , content :: Content a
  }
```

There are a few things going on here.

First, note that in the `File` record, the `content` field now has type `Content a` instead of just `a`. `Content` is a type family,  which is (in my opinion) a confusing name for type-level function. That is, the compiler replaces `Content a` with some other type based on what `a` is and how we've defined `Content`.

We defined `Content Full` to be `String`, so that when we have a value `f1 :: File Full`, its content field will have a `String` value. On the other hand, `f2 :: File Info` will have a `content` field with type `Void` which has no values.

Cool right? But what's preventing us from having `File Foo` now?

That's where `DataKinds` comes to the rescue. It "promotes" the data type `Desc` to a kind (the type of types in Haskell) and type constructors ,`Info` and `Full`, to types of kind `Desc` instead of merely values of type `Desc`.

Notice in the declaration of `Content` that I have annotated `a`. It looks like a type annotation, but `a` is already a type. This is a kind annotation. It forces `a` to be something of kind `Desc` and the only types of kind `Desc` are `Info` and `Full`.

By now you're probably totally sold on how awesome this is, but I should warn you there's no free lunch. In particular, this is a *compile*-time construction. Your single `File` type becomes two different types. This can cause other related logic (producers and consumers of `File` records) to become complicated. If your use case doesn't mix `File Info` records with `File Full` records, then this is the way to go. On the other hand, if you want to do something like have a list of `File` records which can be a mixture of both types, then you're better off just making the type of your `content` field `Maybe String`.

Another thing is, how exactly do you make a `File Info` since there's no value of `Void` to use for the `content` field?  Well, technically it should be ok to use `undefined` or `error "this should never happen"` since it is (morally) impossible to have a function of type `Void -> a`, but if that makes you feel uneasy (and it probably should), then just replace `Void` with `()`. Unit is almost as useless and doesn't require 'values' of bottom.

Answer (score 4):

All of the following are equivalent/isomorphic, as I think you've discovered:

```
data F = U | X A B | Y A B C

data F = U | X AB | Y AB C
data AB = AB A B

data F = U | X A B (Maybe C)
```

So the color of the bike shed really depends on the context (e.g. do you have use for an `AB` elsewhere?) and your own aesthetic preferences.

It might clarify things and help you understand what you're doing to have some sense of [the algebra of algebraic data types](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)

We call types like `Either` "sum types" and types like `(,)` "product types" and they are subject to the same kinds of transformations you're familiar with like factoring

```
f = 1 +            (a * b) + (a * b * c) 
  = 1 + ((a * b) * (  1    +          c))
```

Comment: You're trading one evil for another. In one case you have code duplication. In the other, you have annoying extra injections and projections.

Comment: @pyon Pattern synonyms can simplify the needed injections/projections, at the cost of more boilerplate code in the definitions.

Comment: @pyon you'll have to propose something you consider non-evil then; to me they are (without other context) all equally fine, and this whole discussion a little boring tbh. In addition to pattern synonyms: basic records, alternate records libraries like `lens`, `RecordWildCards`, view patterns, etc.